# Developing a program that serves as a web program in C#

Tags: c#, java, web-services

I'm not sure if I'm going to be able to explain it right since I'm quite sure I don't know the correct terminology involved with it, which is also why I'm having a difficult time Googling for answers.

Essentially, I'm looking to develop a program that serves as a web site.  It'll run constantly (like a service) and will return HTML when an outside user sends an HTTP request thru a browser or similar to a specific port on the computer this program runs on.  Basically, this program will perform various background errands throughout the day but I want to be able to expose a web front end (almost like how you would with standard WinForms, but I want to be able to access it remotely) to be able to configure it, check the status of tasks, and otherwise interact with it.

I'm looking to use .Net, but I'm open to using something more universal like Java too.  Someone with experience in this area would be helpful to explain any pain points you've encountered and suggestions on how to get started.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't understand what you are looking for? Simple sampling would be helpful for the people who can help you.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this.  node.js is one way.  ASP.NET Web Services is another.  ASP.NET MVC, configured as a REST resource, is another.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in C# with the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

I published an example some time back. See [A Simple Http Server](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=784).

Although you might consider whether you really want to operate at that low level. I have written a fairly complex server based on `HttpListener`, and if I had it to do over again I'd probably just bite the bullet and use ASP.NET. There is a bit of a learning curve, but unless your server is incredibly small and simple, an ASP.NET application will be a lot easier to write and will likely be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example on how to do it in C# using the HttpServer class:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C

Comment: Please read: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: yep, noted! but when a question that is so generic/typical that a simple googling will find scores of perfectly valid examples, only deserves that much, imo :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing at least 2 different things, so you should probably create a Solution in Visual Studio.NET with one project for each purpose (You can have many projects in a solution), probably with at least one Data Access project as well (of type Class Library). If the solution does things at certain times of the day, then those can be Console Applications that run through task scheduler, rather than one of more services. Services are better suited to things other than simple scheduled tasks. A Web Application project can serve up your html.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but the answers that this question is attracting are of generally poor quality, so I'm going to go ahead and close the question.